# Push-Notification services for iOS: Bypassing the APN Keys and Apple Store fees using a service offering an iOS app

Tags: ios, push-notification, debian, apple-push-notifications

I have been using pushbullet for months but something happened a week ago and I cannot get to send my pushes. Support has been horrendous.

So I decided to look for an alternative.

I ended up using Pusher which seems fairly promising and support is prompt.

Unfortunately, they don't seem to have an official application and, instead, aim towards a "build you own application to interact with your back-end server"

Which is great! Especially for Android, as APKs can be installed with no certificates without too much hassle.

iOS on the other end is tied to a $100+ fee to enroll as an Apple Dev and publish apps in their store.

**Question:**
Is there a reliable and easy push-notification service/software that I can install on my backend to be able to push a highly reliable and fast notification on my iOS device(s) via AN EXISTING APP (not MY app ... an existing official app, like pushbullet!).

Comment: _iOS on the other end is tied to a $100+ fee to enroll as an Apple Dev and publish apps in their store._ I'm not sure I understand, aren't you already paying that fee in order to publish the app?

Comment: @AMC My point being, I do not have a dev enrolled account and do not want to pay a fee for a simple app for one device. Hence, I'm looking for a service like pushbullet/pusher which has their own application. Also, "on the other end", I was making a comparison to Android, which doesn't need anything. You can run any APK on your android device without an issue or being rooted.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you mean now. I'm not too sure about the Android vs iOS part, though; You can't modify the iOS app to integrate the notification system?

Comment: @AMC Modify what iOS app? My entire question is: Is there an app.

Comment: _Modify what iOS app?_ You're looking to add push notifications to an existing app of yours, no?

Comment: @AMC He spends 4 phrases saying he wants to bypass the enrolling fee and you still don't understand he wants a service with an existing app to prevent having to pay the fee. Title: "Bypassing the APN Keys and Apple Store fees using a service offering an iOS app"

Comment: how's that related to Debian?

Comment: @umläute It's my server's OS, implying the service back-end would need to be debian compatible as the push notification event will be triggered by a node.js script.

Comment: @OakDev _He spends 4 phrases saying he wants to bypass the enrolling fee and you still don't understand he wants a service with an existing app to prevent having to pay the fee._ I'm trying, I was getting lost in the phrasing!

Comment: "Just learn to code"  They said. "It's just like math" They said.

Answer (score 0):

Pushbullet was apparently having issues as everything came back.

It took a long time and was not advertised.